# Problems and artifacts when I do the rendering of the animation

Tags: rendering, artifacts

I'm french and this is the first time I use Blender. I created a little animation on it the last week but when I want to do the rendering there are some artifacts on it and I don't know how to get rid of them. If someone could help me I would be really glad about it. There is a link to the video of the render and the blend file if you need it.

[image: example render]

Animation: https://youtu.be/GuwKHlZ3SBE

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11SmU3pW7wmvM1H2N916VF36UijV-Y_HJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello, could you please show a screenshot where you'd highlight the artefacts you're talking about? Also if you're french you could join this new forum; https://blendertribu.forumactif.com/

Comment: The mesh of the letters is not ideal. It has a lot of vertices that are at the same spot (duplicated vertices) and the letters are jagged. The raggedness casts shadows that lead to these artifacts. Either remesh the letters and smooth them with the *Smooth* brush or rebuild them in a clean way: https://youtu.be/TC-qyGzRyeQ

Comment: In the *Solid* view you can see the irregularities especially when you turn on the Cavity overlay and choose a matcap with high contrast: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP17x.jpg

Comment: well, thank you for all the comments. I will remesh the letters to upgrade the render but I have another problem, on the objects of the background there is also some artifacts but I think it comes from the reflection on the surface and I don't know how to deal with this. The artifacts are visible on this image: https://i.imgur.com/vcqprgc.png